# Use strings as slice indices in Python ? (TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method)

Tags: python, string, class, indexing, slice

I have a sorted array:

```
arr = ['Alexander', 'Belman', 'Erik', 'Nicholas', ... , 'Zahir']
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
arr['B':'M'] # ['Belman', 'Erik']
```

How can I create a class and implement

```
__getitem__
```

```
__index__
```

in the right way to achieve this ?

I am thinking of using something like

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, slice):
        return [self.list[i] for i in range(key.start, key.stop)]
    return self.list[key]
```

but I don't know how to index the strings. How can I create an

```
__index__
```

method to apply a binarySearch to `self.list` and return the correct indices ?

Comment: I'm not sure why would `arr['B':'M']` provide the output you provided. Maybe you meant `arr['B':'N']`? also, what would happen if more than one string start with the same letter?

Comment: why do you want to do this? can you give more context?

Comment: python as a `bisect` library

Comment: The problem is not defined precisely enough. Do you want, for example, to be able to use strings longer than one character, like this: arr['Bel':'Ni'] ?

Comment: Indexing with strings only works when the characters can be converted to numeric or at least order. In your case, the letters of the alphabet could be replaced by the alphabetical index. a = 0, b = 1, c = 2 and so on. `ord(x)-97` would do that, with x being a, b, c, ...

Comment: @DeepSpace It won't provide it. I need a way to define ```__getitem__``` or ```__index__``` method in order to achieve this behavior.

Comment: @entropyfeverone but *why* would it? what is the logic behind it?

Comment: @DeepSpace My goal is that instead of having slices representing indices, I want to override the __getitem__ method in order to use slices in the values (not the indices). But the values are sorted (just like indices) so I was hoping of an easy way to accomplish this. For example if I have ```sl = slice('asd','fdg')``` I want to get all the strings s between these two values (with common <,>,= operators). But I have problem defining ```__getitem__``` in the correct way.

Comment: Is this an example of what you want [Indexing Lists in Python With an Integer or Object’s Name](https://blog.petrzemek.net/2014/10/11/indexing-python-lists-with-integer-or-object-name/)?  It overrides __getitem__

Comment: @DarrylG Thanks ! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get away with as simple implementation as below:

```
from collections import UserList

class MyList(UserList):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            return [e for e in self.data if key.start <= e < key.stop]
        # TODO implement the rest of the usecases and/or error handling...
        #      for now slicing with integers will miserably fail,
        #      and basic integer indexing returns None

arr = MyList(['Alexander', 'Belman', 'Erik', 'Nicholas', 'Zahir'])
print(arr['B':'M'])
```

which will output

```
['Belman', 'Erik']
```

likewise,

```
print(arr['Alex':'Er'])
```

will output

```
['Alexander', 'Belman']
```

Note that I used `key.start <= e < key.stop` to be in line with the inclusive:exclusive (`[)`) behavior which is used throughout python.

Also note that I implemented only the string slices usecase. You can implement the other usecases and error handling as you see fit.

Comment: Great solution.  [Indexing Lists in Python With an Integer or Object’s Name](https://blog.petrzemek.net/2014/10/11/indexing-python-lists-with-integer-or-object-name/) shows how to handle the issue of "for now slicing with integers will miserably fail" by delegating this to ` __getitem__` from list.

Answer (score 0):

I also post my solution with binary search using numpy

```
class Stock():

    def __init__(self, name, date):
        self.name = name
        self.date = np.array(date)


    def __getitem__(self, key):

        if isinstance(key, slice):
            if key.start is not None and key.stop is not None: 
                return self.date[np.searchsorted(self.date, key.start, side='left', sorter=None):np.searchsorted(self.date, key.stop, side='left', sorter=None)]
            elif key.start is not None:
                return self.date[np.searchsorted(self.date, key.start, side='left', sorter=None):]
            elif key.stop is not None:
                return self.date[:np.searchsorted(self.date, key.stop, side='left', sorter=None)]
            else:
                return self.date[:]

        i = np.searchsorted(self.date, key, side='left', sorter=None)
        if key != self.date[i]:
            raise KeyError('key: {} was not found!'.format(key))
        else:
            return self.date[i]



aapl = Stock('aapl', ['2010','2012', '2014', '2016', '2018'])

print(aapl['2011':])
print(aapl['2014':'2017'])
print(aapl[:'2016'])
print(aapl['2010'])
print(aapl['2013'])

'''
['2012' '2014' '2016' '2018']
['2014' '2016']
['2010' '2012' '2014']
2010
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\...\stock.py", line ##, in <module>
    print(aapl['2013'])
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\...\stock.py", line ##, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError('key: {} was not found!'.format(key))
KeyError: 'key: 2013 was not found!'
'''
```